# Only updates from MySQL Workbench diagram/Model?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

After creating an initial schema, is there a way to alter that schema and export only the alterations when working w/ Workbench Models?

Use case being -- there's a live database running the old schema and no data is to be lost, but new updates need to happen.

Comment: What changes are you making to the schema?

Comment: Adding columns here and there, few tables -- so far not any sort of data conversion, but bonus points if the solution can handle that. =D

Comment: If you are only adding columns and tables - then the "Synchronize Model" or "Synchronise with Any Source" commands under the Database menu in MySQL Workbench (when you have the model open) should do the job with no data loss. You can step through & review the final SQL commands prior to running them if you like. Try it out on a test schema first - see what happens. I have done this on several occasions on live databases without problems but I would recommend creating a backup of your live database before hand - better safe than sorry.

Comment: If there are data conversions then MySQL will do it'd best to handle that - but it may have impact on your queries & any processing on the data. Anything complicated I would do in several stages - first add temporary columns, then perform the required conversions into the temporary columns then drop the original columns & rename the temporary columns.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you very much for the "Database" => "Synchronise with Any Source" suggestion

Comment: moderators: don't close the question, it's a valid one. @PaulF why don't you post your comment as answer? That way RossTheBoss can accept it and you get the points for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Mike Lischke - my comments reposted as answer - but only so it can be marked as such when searching SO not for the points.

If you are only adding columns and tables - then the "Synchronize Model" or "Synchronise with Any Source" commands under the Database menu in MySQL Workbench (when you have the model open) should do the job with no data loss. You can step through & review the final SQL commands prior to running them if you like. Try it out on a test schema first - see what happens. I have done this on several occasions on live databases without problems but I would recommend creating a backup of your live database before hand - better safe than sorry.

If there are data conversions then MySQL will do it'd best to handle that - but it may have impact on your queries & any processing on the data. Anything complicated I would do in several stages - first add temporary columns, then perform the required conversions into the temporary columns then drop the original columns & rename the temporary columns.